# Can't figure out this recursion program

Tags: java, recursion

I can't seem to figure out why this recursion program prints the values the way it does. I thought it would print [9]9 first but intead it does it backwards from [0]0. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
class RecTest {
    int values[];
    
    RecTest (int i){
        values = new int[i];
    }
    
    void printArray(int i) {
        if(i==0) return;
        else printArray(i-1);
        System.out.println("[" + (i-1) + "]" + values[i-1]);
    }
}
```

```
public class Recursion2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RecTest ob = new RecTest (10);
        int i;
        
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) ob.values[i] = i;
        
        ob.printArray(10);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The `print`ing happens after the recursive call - "on the way up". I recommend executing the algorithmy "by hand", with a sheet of paper and a pen. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Rookery, Try to visualize call-stack with a small value. for example, let's take printArray(2) will call printArray(1), which will call printArray(0). from here stack will return and printing expression will start.

Comment: Hint: take a piece of paper and a pen. Write down exactly what calls happen, and what the variables and actions are.

Answer (score 1):

The **printArray** method works by calling itself decreasing the integer **i**. The `System.out.println` statement is executed **after** calling the function with **i-1**. For example, given an input of *10*:

1. `printArray(10)` is exectued -> `printArray(10-1)` is called
2. `printArray(9)` is executed -> `printArray(9-1)` is called
3. [...]
4. `printArray(0)` is executed -> `return`. The program goes back to the previous istance of **printArray**, the one where **i = 1**
5. We are here in the code: the line `printArray(1-1)` has just been executed.  The next line is `System.out.println("[" + (1-1) + "]" + values[1-1])` -> `[0]0` is printed (right now **i = 1**). Now the program goes back to the previous instance where **i = 2**
6. [...]

I think you can figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```
static void printVal(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        System.out.printf("Calling printVal(%d) again%n", i-1);
        printVal(i-1);
    }
    System.out.println("Returning from print - call stack has " + i);
}

printVal(10);
```

prints

```
Calling printVal(9) again
Calling printVal(8) again
Calling printVal(7) again
Calling printVal(6) again
Calling printVal(5) again
Calling printVal(4) again
Calling printVal(3) again
Calling printVal(2) again
Calling printVal(1) again
Calling printVal(0) again
Returning from print - call stack has 0
Returning from print - call stack has 1
Returning from print - call stack has 2
Returning from print - call stack has 3
Returning from print - call stack has 4
Returning from print - call stack has 5
Returning from print - call stack has 6
Returning from print - call stack has 7
Returning from print - call stack has 8
Returning from print - call stack has 9
Returning from print - call stack has 10
```

Each subsequent call to `printVal` puts the `value-1` on the call stack. When they are all finally returned, they return in the reverse order.